# Cakephp routing rule like .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp

I want to erase and clean my code a bit.

I have this rule in .htaccess

```
   RewriteRule ^(.+),(.+),(.+),([0-9]+).php$ /hotels/description/$4/3
   RewriteRule ^(.+)+(.+)-([0-9]+).php$ /hotels/description/$3/4
   RewriteRule ^([0-9]+).php.*$ /hotels/description/$1/1
   RewriteRule ^([0-9]+).htm.*$ /hotels/description/$1/2
```

I want to earase that and make cakephp routing rule.

I need something like this:

```
Router::connect('/:descId',
    array('controler' => 'hotels', 'action' => 'description'),
    array(
        'descId' => '[0-9]+'
    ),
    array('pass'=>array('descId'))
);
```

Sadly that does not work at all. It is looking for controller. Cause the validation [0-9] does not work.

```
Missing Controller

Error: 18182.phpController could not be found.

Error: Create the class 18182.phpController below in file: app\controllers\18182.php_controller.php

<?php
class 18182.phpController extends AppController {

    var $name = '18182.php';
}
?>
```

I am only able to make it work if I delete the rule.

```
Router::connect('/:descId',
    array('controler' => 'hotels', 'action' => 'description'),
    array('pass'=>array('descId'))
);
```

The problem will be when I will make another rules for link like:

domain.com/Country,Region,Hotel,Number.php

Can someone help me write those rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Router::connect('/:descId',
    array('controller' => 'hotels', 'action' => 'description'),
    array(
        'pass' => array('descId'),
        'descId' => '[0-9]+',
));
```

Comment: actually I done it myself now, but thanks for help. There is wrong example in cakebook for it so I was mistaken by it. My working example: Router::connect('/:gid.php', array('controller' => 'hotels', 'action' => 'description'),array('gid' => '[0-9]+','pass'=>array('gid')));